# Open Layers 6: Is it possible to get the layer from a feature?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I do have a Open Layers map that consists of different vector layers. All layers have selectable features.

When a feature is selected, I am passing that feature object around in my React app. Now, at some points in my app it would be handy to know what the corresponding layer of that feature is.

Is that possible?

Edit: To be more precise. Is there sth like a getLayer() method on a  Feature? I have not found anything in the docs: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html

Comment: There is no build in function to get the layer from a feature but you could set a custom property on the feature.

Comment: The Feature itself does not know the layer it is in, but the layer knows its features, you can check e.g. via the `hasFeature`-Method of the VectorSource. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#:~:text=The%20url.-,hasFeature,-(feature)%7Bboolean

Comment: You can do this by setting a property on the feature. 
1) Lets say you have a layer called `myLayer`. 
2) Then you can set a property on the feature: `feature.set('layerName', 'myLayer')`.
3) And to know which layer a feature is part of: `feature.get('layerName')` `// 'myLayer'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually make a connection between layers and features. You can do this by setting custom properties, which are key-value pairs.

```js
feature1.set('layerName', 'layerA');
feature2.set('layerName', 'layerB');

feature1.get('layerName'); // 'layerA'
feature2.get('layerName'); // 'layerB'
```